# jquery function works only once

Tags: jquery, function

I dont have brightest idea why this function works only once.. Any ideas?

```
var ColorsTable = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'gold', 'white', 'black'];
var Rand = ColorsTable[Math.floor(Math.random() * ColorsTable.length)];
var Rand2 = ColorsTable[Math.floor(Math.random() * ColorsTable.length)];

jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    $('.losuj').click(function () {
        $("#rama").css("background", Rand);
        $("#rama2").css("background", Rand2);
                var input = $('#wpis');
                input.val('')
                input.val(input.val() + Rand);
                var input2 = $('#wpis2');
                input2.val('')
                input2.val(input2.val() + Rand2);
    }); });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U6MFp/5/

Comment: Because you're passing in the value of `Rand` instead of generating a new random value each time it runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The random colors are only calculated once at pageload, move that inside the click handler

```
var ColorsTable = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'gold', 'white', 'black'];


jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.losuj').click(function () {
        var Rand = ColorsTable[Math.floor(Math.random() * ColorsTable.length)];
        var Rand2 = ColorsTable[Math.floor(Math.random() * ColorsTable.length)];
        $("#rama").css("background", Rand);
        $("#rama2").css("background", Rand2);
        var input = $('#wpis');
        input.val('')
        input.val(input.val() + Rand);
        var input2 = $('#wpis2');
        input2.val('')
        input2.val(input2.val() + Rand2);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/U6MFp/6/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're expecting a different color each time? If that's the case, you're only generating the random colors once when your document loads and using the same values each time.

Try moving the top code inside the function definition like this:

```
var colorsTable = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'gold', 'white', 'black'];

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.losuj').click(function () {
       var rand = colorsTable[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorsTable.length)];
       var rand2 = colorsTable[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorsTable.length)];

       $("#rama").css("background", rand);
       $("#rama2").css("background", rand2);
       $('#wpis').val(input.val() + rand);
       $('#wpis2').val(input2.val() + rand2);
    }); 
});
```